# Executing CMD with Arguments not working

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to execute this CMD command to change my DNS but it is not working.  I don't get any errors. It asks to run as admin however it doesn't work.

If I manually enter the arguments into CMD it does work.

Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo myProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(); 
myProcessInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%") + @"\System32\cmd.exe";
myProcessInfo.Arguments = "set DNS1=198.168.97.1 " +
    "set DNS2=5.2.2.2 " +
    "set DNS3=206.19.29.17 " +
    "set INTERFACE=Ethernet " +
    "netsh int ipv4 set dns name='%INTERFACE%' static %DNS1% primary validate=no " +
    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS2% index=2 " +
    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS3% index=3" +
    "ipconfig /flushdns";

myProcessInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
myProcessInfo.Verb = "runas"; 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myProcessInfo);
```

Comment: These are three separate commands to execute one by one (or put in a batch file and run it) and you don't need to set anything because you can type the value of the set= directly inside the netsh. Also when you start a CMD.EXE processor you should always add the parameter /K or /C in front of your arguments

Comment: You could try using ``&&`` to separate commands. Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator ``&&`` are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @Darek you think that'd work?

Comment: It might, but I'd not use this approach. I'd ask the OS for a temp file using ``Path.GetTempFileName()``, make sure it has a ``BAT`` or ``CMD`` extensions, output all the lines using ``File.WriteAllLines`` and call it with ``$"CMD.exe /C {tempFileName}"``. Than I guarantee it will work.

Comment: @Darek how can i do that?  Can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are doing is appending all your commands as normal arguments. Either run the Command Line for every single command or add the `&` symbol between the commands to chain them. Also, you need to use the `/c`-argument to hand a command over. So your code would look like this:

```
myProcessInfo.Arguments = "/c 'set DNS1=198.168.97.1 && " +
                                    "set DNS2=5.2.2.2 && " +
                                    "set DNS3=206.19.29.17 && " +
                                    "set INTERFACE=Ethernet && " +
                                    "netsh int ipv4 set dns name='%INTERFACE%' static %DNS1% primary validate=no && " +
                                    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS2% index=2 && " +
                                    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS3% index=3 && " +
                                    "ipconfig /flushdns'";
```

Comment: Thanks but this still did not work.  it did not change the DNS.

Comment: Can you check if it works in a normal command-line? I am not on a Windows-device currently, so this is only based on assumptions.

Comment: I'm talking about the command in my post, I hope that was clear. If so, remove the window-style and check the output. I'd be interested in why its not working if the command does work in a normal command line.

Comment: You shoudl be using ``&&``, not ``&``.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".cmd";
File.WriteAllLines(tempFileName, new[]
{
    "set DNS1=198.168.97.1 ", 
    "set DNS2=5.2.2.2 ",
    "set DNS3=206.19.29.17 ",
    "set INTERFACE=Ethernet ",
    "netsh int ipv4 set dns name='%INTERFACE%' static %DNS1% primary validate=no ",
    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS2% index=2 ",
    "netsh int ipv4 add dns name='%INTERFACE%' %DNS3% index=3",
    "ipconfig /flushdns"
});

var myProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
myProcessInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%") 
    + @"\System32\cmd.exe /C " + tempFileName;
myProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
var myProcess = Process.Start(myProcessInfo);
if (myProcess != null)
    while (!myProcess.HasExited)
    {
        myProcess.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
File.Delete(tempFileName);
```

Comment: God no, this is terrible. The idea of an array is not too bad, but then at least execute every single command, without writing to a file. Writing to a file gives a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Executing every single line serves no purpose. Every set will be in its own context. It must be executed as one line with ``&&`` or a batch file. I have no confidence to extending the command line indefinitely, there are limits.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to see that. In this case, this solution is indeed okay, although I'd prefer the solution above. I personally would write a chaining function that can be passed an array and returns a valid cmd argument.